# Calling subfunctions directly

Tags: matlab, function

Imagine I implement a function that calls a subfunction. Keeping the subfunction in the `.m` file keeps things more compact, so I'd like to do that. However, for debugging purposes, I need to call that subfunction. I try to do that, and I get `File not found`, or a similar error. Is there a way to call a subfunction that is in the same `.m` file as another function from outside that function?

Comment: As far as I know you can't, as the function is not defined within the scope of where you're calling it.  Check out: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92762-why-am-i-unable-to-run-a-subfunction-from-outside-its-main-function-or-as-a-callback-function for more details.  It'll give you some hints on how to achieve this if you must... but the easiest way is to create a new `.m` file with this function defined in it.

Comment: For a similar issue I switched to private functions in a private directory. The can be accessed using the full path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612002/how-to-isolate-unittests-in-matlab/24616475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around this. If you want to call a function from the command prompt or from multiple .m files you must put it into a separate .m file.

The only possible alternative is to have a class with multiple public methods.