# How to call an m file directly from another m file in MATLAB without add its folder path

Tags: matlab

How to call an m file from another m file in MATLAB without add its folder path?
I don't want to add its folder via

```
addpath(genpath(''))
```

Comment: can you give a good reason why you don't want to add the path? - Your alternative is to copy and paste that .m file to your working directory (which is somewhat silly).

Comment: I want a folder that have multiple .m file. I don't want use another m file in that folder in my main function. also I can not use copy because of duplication.

Comment: Well, as @GameOfThrows said, there's two options when it comes to calling .m-files: copy the file to your current working directory *or* use `addpath`. As far as I know there isn't another option to do this, even a call to the `fullpath` of the file and then trying to `eval` or `feval` doesn't work.

Comment: That is the idea of a working directory right? You can have your main function in say  file:///home/project/ ; and your function codes in file:///home/project/functions?

Comment: I have a big project. I have a folder with accessory files and folder for main function. some accessory files customize for my main function and another some are fix. because of this, I want to use certain accessory file in my main function

Comment: If it is a function you need to `cd` into the path or add the path to your MATLAB path. If it is a script you can do the above or use [`run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html)

Comment: @excaza: That's true, but then again all functions are visible. I understood the second comment in a way that only one function should be visible. Using cd is probably the standard way to expose such functions for unit tests, at least I use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612002/how-to-isolate-unittests-in-matlab/24616475#24616475)

Comment: @Daniel yes, but it's the only way to accomplish what he is asking. If he wants to call a specific file then he can write a small wrapper function, pass the full path and any inputs, call the function, then return to the previous directory. This is all `run` does (minus inputs because it's scripts only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All visibility rules for functions are based on Folders. If you want to have different visibilities you have to place your functions in different folders.

Typically, avoiding duplicate function names and just adding all source files to your search path is what works. To avoid duplicate function names you may want to take a look at packages.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the functionality of MATLAB's built-in [`run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) for scripts, you can [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) into the secondary path, execute your function, and then return to the previous directory.

A small example:

```
% testcode.m
function [output] = testcode(fullfunctionpath, A, B)
[pathname, functionName] = fileparts(fullfunctionpath);
olddir = cd(pathname);

output = feval(functionName, A, B);
cd(olddir);
end

% .\test\testing.m
function [output] = testing(A, B)
output = A + B;
end
```

With the call:

```
C = testcode('C:\testcode-matlab\test\testing.m', 1, 2);
```

Will return

```
C =

     3
```

Note that this approach does not have error handling nor does it check for duplicates that already exist in your path definition. If the called function is not present in the target folder but does exist in the path, the function in MATLAB's path will still be executed. See: [Function Precedence Order](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) for more information.