# How can I call builtin functions that aren't builtin?

Tags: matlab, built-in

[`table()`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) has been a standard function in MATLAB since R2013b. As far as I can see from the documentation, there's nothing special about `table`, compared to `sum`, `cell`, `struct`,  or any other [builtin function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist.html).

However, when I try to run the function using `builtin('table',var1,...varN)` I get an error saying:

> Error using builtin
>
> Cannot find builtin function 'table'

Investigating this further shows that it is in fact not considered a builtin function:

```
which('cell')
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\cell)

which('table')
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@table\table.m  % table constructor
|
Not builtin
```

Investigating further:

```
which cell2mat
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\cell2mat.m

which mat2cell
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\mat2cell.m

which table2array
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\table2array.m

which struct2cell
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@struct\struct2cell)  % struct method

which cell2struct
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@cell\cell2struct)  % cell method
```

So, `cell` is builtin while `table` is not. `cell2struct` is builtin while `cell2mat` is not.

Why is this, and is there a simple way to call overloaded standard functions that aren't considered builtin by MATLAB?

---

<sub>If you think the *why* part is "too broad", please disregard it and jump to the last part of the question.</sub>

Comment: Built-ins are generally compiled due to their frequency of use and/or take an undesirable amount of time to run as `*.m` files. There used to be a tech doc somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Makes sense =) But wouldn't it make sense to compile `cell2mat` if they compile `cell2struct`?

Comment: Maybe. But as is often the case with development, dev teams may have internal knowledge that makes things not as simple as they seem to folks outside.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: [compiled is not always faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166847/faster-version-of-find-for-sorted-vectors-matlab/20167257#20167257), often used does not mean that it should be compiled.

Comment: To answer the explicit question, the "simple" method would probably be to use `which` with `cd` and `feval`, similar to what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35153710/2748311)

Comment: @excaza: which won't tell you the path.

Comment: @Daniel what? `a = which('table')` returns the path...

Comment: Yes it does, but once you have a different function called `table` it no longer works. I think this is the interesting use case for such a function.

Comment: Of course it works, use the `'-all'` flag and parse the returned cell array for the function located in the 'MATLAB' toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the native function(s) by something like:

```
allTables = which  ( '-all', 'table' )
allTables(cell2mat(strfind ( allTables, matlabroot )))
```

Its not fullproof and for some functions (e.g. sum) there are a lot in the root folders...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation page for `builtin` gives a clear definition:

> A built-in function is part of the MATLAB executable. MATLAB does not implement these functions in the MATLAB language. Although most built-in functions have a .m file associated with them, this file only supplies documentation for the function.